# Windows: Open new windows on top of last (not offsetting downward)

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-registry

Whenever opening a new window in Windows (explorer or other apps), the new one opens at an offset, cascading all resulting windows downward. It happens with almost everything, whether it's a new folder (via Ctrl-N for example) or opening a new browser window, etc etc.

Is there a way or a registry setting that opens all new windows exactly on top of the last (or always at a given screen pixel location, say 1x,1y)?

*Note: I'm aware of (and use) utils like cmdow, ahk, nircmd etc (as noted in comment below). I'm aiming to change Windows's default offsetting behavior across the board. Thanks.*

Thank you very much.

Comment: Would this help? [Set The Window Position of an application via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977322/set-the-window-position-of-an-application-via-command-line?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: I already use cmdnow, ahk, (and also nircmd) etc for positioning specific windows. However, I'm looking for a way to open folders, other app-created windows whose titles or ids are not known, or which may not be active beforehand. Thanks.